# Select Element in Python Selenium for Dropdown Menu

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am new to Python and I am trying to use Selenium to select a value from a drop down menu on a Firefox browser.

This is what is am trying. Please let me know what I am doing wrong:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('URL')

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('Yesterday'))
```

[image]

I need to add the following to my original post:

I have used Selenium IDE to try and identify the selector. Please image below. I would like to select "Yesterday" from the drop down list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe2RQ.png)

Comment: what is the locator of Select

Comment: Please check my answer,

Comment: How many drop downs are present in the page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,  locate `Select` drop down then select the **Custom** value

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('locator of the select'))
select.select_by_value('Custom')
```

Also, you can use the index

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('locator of the select'))
select.select_by_index(6)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my post and added a screenshot the selection through Selenium IDE. I am still trying to figure out how to code this in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser.find_element_by_link_text("Yesterday") in place of browser.find_element_by_id. Since it does not contain an id tag it will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my post and added a screenshot the selection through Selenium IDE. I am still trying to figure out how to code this in Python.